# Resolving Instances with Delegates in Unity

Tags: .net, unity-container, enterprise-library, structuremap

Has Unity, since February of 2011, [improved this delegate story](https://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/resolving-instances-using-delegates-in-unity/) to achieve parity with StructureMap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Actually, this shipped with Unity 1.0 as the injection factory extension, so the blog post is wrong about the capability not being there.

In Unity 2.0 the story got a lot easier. You can do:

```
container.RegisterType<IWhatever>(
    new InjectionFactory(container => whateverFunctionYouWant()));
```

This results in a transient registration; you can use whatever lifetime manager you want.